# AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: datetime, dataframe, format, attributeerror

For a test to understand and be able to change format as I desire..tried the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['07/14/2009 00:00', '07/14/2009 00:30'])
pd.to_datetime(df,format=%Y%m%d)
```

This format is exactly as in this [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Yet on my mac terminal it returned the AttributeError on %Y. How may I understand this and resolve it? Kindly let me know :(

Answer (score 0):

Your *df* variable looks like it should be a Series instead of a DataFrame from what I could tell in that link. Your format also does not match up with the format of your variable.

Comment: so.. I tried instead by defining as Series variable, and used %Y-%m-%d %I:%M but it returns `ValueError: time data '07/14/2009 00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M' (match)`. I find this [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) quite unhelpful..how am I to format?

Comment: I want to know how to setup a format..and from where the error is derived,,

Comment: Format would be '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'.